# Ubuntu: Find and Rename multiple files in different directory

Tags: ubuntu

I need to find and rename all file in Lots of directory.

old

directory1/directory2/directory3/01.MP3
directory1/directory2/directory4/02.MP3

new

directory1/directory2/directory3/01.mp3
directory1/directory2/directory4/02.mp3

just .MP3 To .mp3

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -name '-*' | while read FILE ; do
newfile="$(echo ${FILE} |sed -e 's/\\file/safe/')" ;
rename "${FILE}" "${newfile}" ;
```

Comment: please consider adding more explanation